# GeoJSON from PostGIS view using PDO

Tags: postgis, geojson

I want to use PostGIS data to display it in Leaflet.
I've created a PostGIS view (v_baeume_GeoJSON) that delivers already valid GeoJSON. When I retrieve the data from this view using PDO I have to do a few steps to get again valid data to display it in Leaflet?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bongert.v_baeume_geojson
AS SELECT row_to_json(fc.*) AS geojson
   FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection'::text AS type,
            array_to_json(array_agg(f.*)) AS features
           FROM ( SELECT 'Feature'::text AS type,
                    st_asgeojson(st_transform(lg.the_geom, 4326), 15, 0)::json AS geometry,
                    ( SELECT row_to_json(t.*) AS row_to_json
                           FROM ( SELECT lg.gid,
                                    lg.id_sort) t) AS properties
                   FROM bongert.baeume lg
                   LIMIT 2) f) fc;
```

The data is valid GeoJSON and looks like this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[6.47434138884473,49.8181346585368]},"properties":{"gid":21647,"id_sort":"ap_"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[6.44536728156301,49.6813625945007]},"properties":{"gid":34501,"id_sort":"ap_starearl"}}]}
```

When I use this view as datasource in a PHP script, that is addressed by an AJAX call, I have to strip off parts of the resulting string, since I have problems to get the data 'as it is' out of the script. How can I get the blank data out of the PDO query without the need of JSON encode and the whole preg_replace to get back to the plain result of my view?

```
require("db_connection.php");

$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM bongert.v_baeume_geojson";

$result = $conn->query($query);
$geojson = json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
$geojson = preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"", $geojson);
$prefix = '[{"geojson":"';
$suffix = '"}]';
$geojson = preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($prefix, '/') . '/', '', $geojson);
$geojson = preg_replace('/'.   preg_quote($suffix, '/') . '$/', '', $geojson);
echo($geojson);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading and searching it was quite easy:
instead of using fetchall() I only had to use fetch() since my view only returns one single row. I get the data by choosing the first result of the returned array.

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
$geojson = $result->fetch();
echo($geojson[0]);
```

This works now fine.